# How to correctly generate ES6 target with CommonJS modules in Typescript 1.7?

Tags: typescript

In Typescript 1.7 a feature was added that allows to separately target language system and module system, ex it can produce ES6 code with CommonJS module system for latest node. But if I try it with following command and source code:

```
tsc *.ts --target es6 --module commonjs
```

```
// foo.ts
"use strict";
import Bar from './bar';
console.log(Bar);
```

```
// bar.ts
"use strict";
export default class Bar {}
```

Surprisingly, resulting code have some very strange export notation being generated:

```
// foo.js
"use strict";
var bar_1 = require('./bar');
console.log(bar_1.default);
```

```
// bar.js
"use strict";
class Bar {}
exports.Bar = Bar;
```

As you can see, `bar.js` results in being exporting `Bar` object, while `foo.js` attempts to import `default` object. And of course this code displays "undefined" being imported if executed via latest `nodejs` v4.1.0

Any hints why such strange behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You found a bug in TS 1.7. I believe this is the correct issue:

- https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5594
- and corresponding bugfix https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/5648 that is merged in TS 1.8 master branch.

I verified it by running the code in TS@next (Version 1.8.0-dev.20151216):

```
npm install typescript@next --save
node node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc --target es6 --module commonjs *.ts && node foo.js
```

Comment: Ineed it is! Thanks a lot, I was sure that this functionality being on official "what's new" list is a safeguard that they tested it at last once and it works, so I was sure it is my fault and I don't know something about modern module resolution techniques.